# Why does running a python script with double click, also launches a terminal in background?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I just finish writing my script and for the first time I make a graphical interface with tkinter. When I run the script by double clicking on the file (I'm on W10) the graphical interface run, but I also got a terminal that open in background and I don't know why? Is there a way to remove it?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the file ending to .pyw

Comment: perfect, exactly what i need, thanks